# Ubuntiu 16.04.1 not routing even though routing enabled in kernel

Tags: 16.04, vmware, routing

TL;DR: Fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.01 not routing even after enabling routing in the kernel.

Long version: I am playing with routing using various VMs as routers. I have loaded a fresh VM (VMware Workstation 12.5; host running Win7) with Ubuntu Server 16.4.1 and fully updated it. It has 2 VMware NICs. 
I did the following in configuring the networking:

1. Configured netwoking (ens33 is the "internet" or "external" interface, assigned 192.168.5.5; ens34 is the "internal" interface, assigned 10.0.0.1.
2. enabled ipv4 routing by editing /etc/sysctl.conf and removing the hashtag in front of the ipv4_forwarding line
3. disabled the Ubuntu firewall with "ufw disable" (this VM is behind many other protective measures; the risk associated with not having a firewall on it right now is minimal)
4. Rebooted the VM.

(I am NOT using Network Manager)

There is another Ubuntu VM running 14.04 behind the router VM, located at 10.0.0.2.

All should be well, right? Except the router is not routing packets from the 14.04 workstation.

The router VM itself *can* communicate with the Internet. It can ping both the Internet and the workstation behind it, it can apt-get, etc. The workstation can ping the router, but nothing past the router.

In terms of troubleshooting, I have:

1. Checked that /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward = 1. It does.
2. Checked that the firewall was disabled. It is.
3. tcpdump'ed both interfaces on the router. I can see that the workstation's pings are getting forwarded from the internal interface to the external interface and sent on, BUT I can ALSO see that the responses are hitting the external i/f and NOT getting forwarded back.
4. Tried different virtual interfaces
5. Tried different IP addressing schemes
6. Even tried a loading up a different VM with a different distro (Debian 8) to be the router. Same result.

The thing is, I *do* have other, older router VMs that *do* work. I have a Debian 7 VM configured for routing that does work. It's just that this new one won't.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!